# How to bind a popover from code behind C#

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap

I have a span like this with the popOver:

```
<div class="container">
  <span title="Header" data-toggle="popover" runat="server" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Some content">Hover over me</span>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>
```

is there any possibility to bind the data-content from code behind in C#??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way, I think you want to change the content in an event rigth? First you need to assign an Id to your `<span>`

```
<span ID="spanPopOver" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" runat="server" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Some content">Hover over me</span>
```

then with the code inside the event should be enough

```
protected void yourControlToBeClicked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    spanPopOver.Attributes["data-content"] = "the new content";
}
```